# Xcode converting project from C++ to Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

how to convert a Xcode C++ project to an Xcode Objective-C++ project, because now it doesn't threat ".mm" files like Objective-C++ files, but as C++ files generating lots of errors:) also cannot use the ObjC++ goodies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you should do:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check in the project configuration under *Build* that *"Compile Sources as"* is set to *"According to file type*.

Alternatively, to change what a file is compiled as: select it, *"Get Info"*, change the file type to e.g. `sourcecode.cpp.objcpp` for ObjC++.

Comment: how can i do that on a bunch of files, without manually setting this value via getinfo? as i see, the .mm are rocognized ok, but theyr headers are recognized as C headers :( not ObjC++ headers, so it is nescessery to change them

Comment: @Peter: Headers shouldn't be getting compiled at all.  The type of the file that includes them will determine how they are compiled.